# How I return specific string from recursive function in java?

Tags: java, recursion, return

**Input for method :**

word = AbcDef

input = 3

w = AbcDef

**The Following code showing the ouput :**

fAbcDe

efAbcD

DefAbc

I want to return only **DefAbc**.
How can I do the coding for return keyword.

```
public static String match2(String word,int input,String w)
{
    StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder st1 = new StringBuilder();
    String str = "";
    int count = 0;
            st.append(word.charAt(i));
            
        for(int j = 0;j < i;j++)
        {
            st.append(word.charAt(j));
                  
        }
        
    
                
    if(input!=0)
    {
        str = st.toString();
        System.out.println(str);
        int input2 = input-1;
        match2(str,input2,w);
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a break inside the first loop? That way ithe first loop is not executed more than once.

Comment: output is correct but i want to return only DefAbc .

Comment: @Shr_c what i wanted you to see, is, your implementation does not make sense - you can remove that first loop entirely and return just add the last character to your StringBuilder st. Same goes for your second loop - the outer is just executed once. So there is not much about explaining how to let your implementation return a special string - if you always want to return DefAbc you do not need an algorithm at all, you can just return this String in the first line. :-) On the other hand you might repair your implementation and explain, what makes the expected String "DefAbc" special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one. Hope it might solve your problem using recursion-> tillValue should be->3 if you want to rotate for 3 characters

```
   static String recurse(String word, int count, int tillValue) {
        if (count == tillValue) {
            return word;
        }

        String recurse = recurse(word, count + 1,tillValue);
        word = swap(recurse);

        return word;
    }

    private static String swap(String word) {
        if (word.length() > 0) {
            String c = word.substring(word.length() - 1);
            String dc = c + word.substring(0, word.length() - 1);
            System.out.println(dc);
            return dc;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: if i want to send the result alternatively to the same method.how can i do it.

Comment: Then you have to put tillValue =1  and you have to put this recurse function in a loop that exactly how much rotation you want.